# WP_Query not returning results

Tags: php, css, query, html

I have problem with my WP_Query, I want to display results with my custom query, I'm using Advanced Custom Fields

```
<?php
// Get data from URL into variables
$miejscowosc = $_GET['miejscowosc'] != '' ? $_GET['miejscowosc'] : '';
$typ_nieruchomosci = $_GET['typ_nieruchomosci'] != '' ? $_GET['typ_nieruchomosci'] : '';
$min = $_GET['price'];
$max = $_GET['price-max'];
//var_dump($typ_nieruchomosci);
// Start the Query
//var_dump($min);
$price = explode('zł -', $min);
$min_1 = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$price[0]);
$max_1 = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$price[1]);
$value = array($min_1, $max_1);
$v_args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'post', // your CPT
      //  's'             =>  $_name, // looks into everything with the keyword from your 'name field'
        'meta_query'    =>  array(
                                array(
                                    'key'     => 'typ_nieruchomosci', // assumed your meta_key is 'car_model'
                                    'value'   => $typ_nieruchomosci,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE', // finds models that matches 'model' from the select field
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'   => 'test',
                                    'value' => $miejscowosc,
                                    'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'   => 'cena_nieruchomości',
                                    'value' => $value,
                                    'type'  => 'NUMERIC',
                                    'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',

                                ),
                            )
    );
$houseQuery = new WP_Query( $v_args );
?>
```

If I have something like this, my WP_Query not return any results, and if I have something like this:

```
<?php
// Get data from URL into variables
$miejscowosc = $_GET['miejscowosc'] != '' ? $_GET['miejscowosc'] : '';
$typ_nieruchomosci = $_GET['typ_nieruchomosci'] != '' ? $_GET['typ_nieruchomosci'] : '';
$min = $_GET['price'];
$max = $_GET['price-max'];
//var_dump($typ_nieruchomosci);
// Start the Query
//var_dump($min);
$price = explode('zł -', $min);
$min_1 = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$price[0]);
$max_1 = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$price[1]);
$value = array($min_1, $max_1);
$v_args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'post', // your CPT
      //  's'             =>  $_name, // looks into everything with the keyword from your 'name field'
        'meta_query'    =>  array(
                                array(
                                    'key'     => 'typ_nieruchomosci', // assumed your meta_key is 'car_model'
                                    'value'   => $typ_nieruchomosci,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE', // finds models that matches 'model' from the select field
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'   => 'test',
                                    'value' => $miejscowosc,
                                    'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'   => 'cena_nieruchomości',
                                    'value' => array(20000, 50000),
                                    'type'  => 'NUMERIC',
                                    'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',

                                ),
                            )
    );
$houseQuery = new WP_Query( $v_args );
?>
```

This returning me my result, what is wrong with my "cena_nieruchomosci" key? I can not use variables in array?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. Topic can be close.

Comment: A sign of good manners could be to explain how did you fix the problem. This site is a knowledge base.

Comment: I changed my min and max value to int `$value = array(intval($min_1), intval($max_1));`

Answer (score 0):

if you print_r($houseQuery), what is your request query? It's a correct SQL query?

When you print WP_Query object you can find this in structure:
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS[...]

You need to analyze this to understand what's going on.

Let me know.